# I am getting this error while executing cmd "rails new test_install" on my windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190220-5856-12t9mtl.rb
extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can

be found here:

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sql
ite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for
inspection.
Results logged to
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/sql
ite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you use rails in 5.2.2 version. Solution is change version of `sqlite` to `1.3.6`:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
```

After this change run command:

```
bundle update
```

Comment: I installed SQLite 1.3.6     C:\>gem install sqlite3 -v 1.3.6  
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.6-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for sqlite3-1.3.6-x86-mingw32
Done installing documentation for sqlite3 after 1 seconds
1 gem installed

C:\>bundle update
The latest bundler is 2.0.1, but you are currently running 1.15.3.
To update, run `gem install bundler`
Could not locate Gemfile

Comment: You have to run `bundle update` in directory with your Rails project.

Comment: The thing is that  I want to create a localhost server for that I need to run above cmd which is rails new test_install.    I have installed sqlite3 v1.3.6 and updated bundler

Comment: Have you read official guide? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. After change version of sqlite go to your application folder in console, run `bundle update` and then start your application using `rails s`. Everything should works.

Comment: still getting the same error, yes I am following a guide in coursera he has done it in the same way, it worked for him.

Comment: an error which I have mentioned in the first comment, could you please tell me how to create localhost:3000. i am totally new to ruby on rails

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue and tried for more than a week a lot of solutions the only one worked for me was uninstall RailsInstaller only install Ruby DevKit (make sure all the folders of RailsInstaller installation are gone or you'll see a message "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin" cannot be found when trying to use gem command) install rails by command line `C:/Sites > gem install rails` and install MinGW

```
C:\Sites>ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-dlfcn
```

Download the SQLite3 gem from https://rubygems.org/, save it locally and install it from file

```
C:\Sites>gem install --local C:\sqlite3-1.4.0.gem
```

The good thing is it worked for all the projects that I created after.

Comment: If it doesn't work or you see a new error message check this https://mycodeissuesandfixes.blogspot.com/2019/02/ruby-on-rails-issue-about-sqlite-3-gem.html. Those are a list of all the solutions I tried and the error messages I got, maybe one of those works for you